# Compare ms-sql database schemas on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, schema

Is there any command in ms-sql (on linux) to compare schemas between two databases?

Answer (score 2):

I have very similar needs (I currently use PostgreSQL on Linux), and if doesn't have to necessarily be a ms-sql command I have 2 possible solutions:

**Solution 1:**
Use mssql-scripter from Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter)
You can get mssql-scripter via for example

```
pip install mssql-scripter.
```

and execute the following commands:

```
$ mssql-scripter -S serverName -d databaseSource -U user > ./source.sql
$ mssql-scripter -S serverName -d databaseTarget -U user > ./target.sql
$ diff source.sql target.sql
```

**Solution 2:**
If you have the possibility to use a desktop environment (as I'm doing) I would use a comparison tools, which is much more user friendly in my opinion.

TiCodeX SQL Schema Compare (https://www.ticodex.com) It's a nice tools that runs in Linux, Windows and Mac and can compare the schema of MS-SQL, MySQL and PostgreSQL database. Easy to use and effective. It may help you.

In order to use it:

- Configure the source db (specifying servername, username, password, etc...)
- Configure the target db
- There are options in case you want to exclude database objects, or change the output
- Press the comparison button

You will get the differences between the two databases, and eventually you also get the migration scripts to make the target db identical to the source.

Comment: Thanks for the links. mssql-scripter and diff does the job for me. I tested as well  ticodex sql schema compare and saw that  it creates migration scripts as well -  But for the moment I don't need this as the changes are easy.

Answer (score 0):

It can perhaps can be done indirectly via
[sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-2017) for Linux.

- Firstly, dacpac of each database to be created:

  `sqlpackage.exe /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:XLW-CNU415CD8B /SourceDatabaseName:AdventureWorks2012 /TargetFile:AdventureWorks2012_v1.dacpac /p:IgnoreExtendedProperties=True /p:IgnorePermissions=False /p:ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly=True`
- Then, dacpacs to be compared:

  `sqlpackage /a:DeployReport /sf:AdventureWorks2012_v1.dacpac /tf:AdventureWorks2012_v2.dacpac /tdn:AdventureWorks2012.db /op:AdventureWorks2012_v1.xml`

Please note that this example is based on a windows version of the tool, I assume that Linux port has the same list of arguments

Comment: Thanks for this solution. As you stated, it works as well on my machine, but mssql-scripter is much faster on my DBs than sqlpackage - the report from sqlpackage is better than diff, but diff does the job for me ;-)